# how to Automatic Update personal Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, webhooks

If I write a private plugin, is there any way to use the WordPress auto-update mechanism to update it?

I want to encapsulate the functionality, but it's specific to my own 5 or so blogs, so it's not a good candidate for the public plugin's resource. But I love the easy updating mechanism.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: did you try with `add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_true' );`?

Comment: I think this is the most famous solution: http://w-shadow.com/blog/2010/09/02/automatic-updates-for-any-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
function auto_update_specific_plugins ( $update, $item ) {
    // Array of plugin slugs to always auto-update
    $plugins = array ( 
        'akismet',          
        'yourplugin',
    );
    if ( in_array( $item->slug, $plugins ) ) {
        return true; // Always update plugins in this array
    } else {
        return $update; // Else, use the normal API response to decide whether to update or not
    }
}
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', 'auto_update_specific_plugins', 10, 2 );
```

[Configuring Automatic Background Updates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates)